Finding a slope of greater than 6 degrees in Google Earth Engine
I'm trying to find areas deeper than 200meters and with slopes greater than 6 degrees on the ocean floor and I'm having trouble figuring out how to determine them. So far I have:
var dem = ee.Image("NOAA/NGDC/ETOPO1");
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(dem);
But I'm having trouble figuring out how to determine which slopes are greater than 6 degrees and how to display those on a map. I'm still at this and don't have much experience on Google Earth Engine, so the answer may be obvious, but I'm struggling to figure it out.

What have you tried so far?

To be fair, I've having a bit of trouble figuring out what I need to do. I had an idea to use ee.Filter.gt but don't have much of an idea on how to implement it. I'm just a bit lost at the moment.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification. If you believe you have solved your own Question, you should should generate an Answer.

I think I may have figured something out. I used the following code to create a this map layer.   var elevation = ee.Image("NOAA/NGDC/ETOPO1").select('bedrock');    var terrain = ee.Terrain.products(elevation);    print('terrain',terrain);     var slope = terrain.select(['slope']);  var hillshade = terrain.select(['hillshade']);  Map.addLayer(hillshade);  Map.addLayer(slope.selfMask(), {palette: ['purple','darkred','black'], min:0, max: 90}, 'slope') It looks alright to me, just wanted to make sure the values were all correct.

I suppose you can do something like this:
var elevation = ee.Image("NOAA/NGDC/ETOPO1").select('bedrock')
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation)

var mask = elevation.lt(200)
  .and(slope.gt(6))

Here, mask will be 1 when elevation is less than 200 and slope is greater than 6. Otherwise it will be 0.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/ca41445a88c410632852a958e22c9215
